# Why free() in C isn't work?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char* in = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    in = "Sort of Input String with LITERALS AND NUMBERS\0";
    free(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Why this code isn't working with this error?

```
pointers(10144,0x7fff78a82000) malloc: *** error for object 0x10ba18f88: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
bash: line 1: 10144 Abort trap: 6           '/Users/.../Documents/term2_sr/pointers'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 134]
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `in` is re-assigned by `in = "Sort of ...";`.

Actually, you're doing `free("Sort of ...");`, which is obviously illegal.

Comment: `in` is a named pointer variable. Thus it is not reallocated. Also the string literal is not (re)allocated.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, "reassigned"

Answer (score 2):

`in` is a pointer.  You set it with `malloc()`, you later change it to point to a literal.  Then you try to free this  poitner to a litteral (which was never allocated on the heap, so causes `free()` to fail) .

To copy a string, you have to use `strcpy()`:

```
char* in = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
strcpy (in, "Sort of Input String with LITERALS AND NUMBERS");
free(in);
```

Actually, in order to avoid accidental buffer overflows, you could also copy the string, taking into consideation its maximum length:

```
strncpy (in, "Sort of Input String with LITERALS AND NUMBERS", 100);
```